# Trying to display an echoed image from a PHP script in and `<img src="..."` tag

Tags: php, html, image

The objective:

1) I have a images folder outside web root where all images from the web app are placed (each image path is saved in a DB table);

2) I want to get that image upon a request from the user.

Simple, right?

I did:

a) Create a class to reads the image (with all security features and safeguards that I can remember). It returns (successfully) the image encoded (base64) with the respective mime type.

b) I've created, for demonstration purposes, a index.php, which has:

`<img src="agivenscript.php?img=name.jpeg">`

My only objective here is to call from any other place in my web app a script that outputs the base64 encoded image with the respective mime type.

c) Created a script "agivenscript.php" that receives the image name by GET, instantiates my class and gets, when all goes right, the base64 encoded image. It then echoes the image.

What happens:

- When I do the output - using echo `'<img src="' . $output64encodedwithmimetype . '">';` - in agivenscript.php it works like a charm;
- Moreover, if I take the $output64encodedwithmimetype contents and place the string directly in the src tag of index.php, it also works.
- However, it does not work when I try `<img src="agivenscript.php?img=name.jpeg">`.

As the base64 encoded image is obviously fine (and has the mime type), what am I missing? Any idea?

Thank in advance.

Comment: why are you storing your images outside the web root ? When visitors will browse your website, the server will have many PHP requests to handle, and you will have to handle the cache mechanism yourself with proper headers (otherwise, your served images won't be cached, that's not really clever nor nice for bandwidth). Images served directly are cached by the browser

Comment: Hi Pierre! Thank you for the comment. Yes, I agree with you. I'm making code examples and want to show how to fetch files (not just images) from outside web root. Cache is not a main concern for now, but I agree that it is vital in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data:` scheme URLs can be Base64 encoded.

HTTP responses of the `image/jpeg` (or png or whatever) **can't**. You need to serve up the actual image data without encoding it as text.

`readfile` is probably all you need.

Comment: Thank you! I want to have the option to serve the image as a response to an HTML request or another PHP script, so I made to simple changes in the code and, when responding to an HTML request I did what you suggested: serve the image directly. It works. Thank you: I was around this question and did not understand why it was not working.